# Designing GameEntity class to store multiple images for character

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I started out with a single Bitmap Image property in my GameEntity abstract class.
I soon realized there could be different images to display based on characteristics and events involving the GameEntity.

For example:

- A character has a different image or blue/pink color based on the
  gender of the character.
- A character may have a different temporary background to indicate he
  just made a noise.
- A character may have a different image to indicate he is actively
  using some equipment.

So I need to transition to storing multiple images in the GameEntity class.
What is the best approach to do this?

Some Ideas:

1. Create a List of Bitmap.  Utilize an Int32 ImageIndex to indicate what the actively displayed image is.
2. Use an ImageList DataType.  Too much overhead?
3. Create a List with values pointing to individual images for the character in a master indexed list of images for all characters?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Player
{
    public class GameEntity
    {
        // Single Image
        Bitmap Image;

        // Multiple Images
        List<Bitmap> Images;
        Int32 CurrentImageIndex;

        // Built-in support?
        ImageList ImageList;

        // Master shared list of images
        List<Int32> ImageIndexes;

        public GameEntity()
        {
            Image = Properties.Resources.RunningManBlue_48x;
            Images = new List<Bitmap>();
            Images.Add(Properties.Resources.RunningManBlue_48x);
            Images.Add(Properties.Resources.RunningManPink_48x);

            CurrentImageIndex = 0;

            ImageList ImageList = new ImageList();

            ImageIndexes = new List<Int32>();
            ImageIndexes.Add(0);
            ImageIndexes.Add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, does C# store the actual data that makes up the bitmap in the image property?
Or does it store a reference that points to the Properties.Resources.ImageXXX?

UPDATE: I decided to make it simple and used the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Index of current image in Images to display.
    /// </summary>
    public Int32 CurrentImage { get; set; } = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Bitmap resources of GameEntity.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract List<Bitmap> Images { get; set; }
```